# Which one is better (or correct) expression? "go up 5 percent'" or "go up by 5 percent"

Tags: phrase-requests, american-english

I ran into some curiosity on some expression just like,

A) It took me a day to go up 5 percent.

B) It took me a day to go up **by** 5 percent.

I think the B is right, but someone is sometimes using the A.

Can you explain for the reason about A and B ?

Thank you.

Comment: I find "go up" odd. Did _you_ really go up 5%, or was it some measure of your performance? Please give a sentence with more context.

Comment: Preposition deletion is mentioned in the [Omission of 'for' with various quantified time intervals: influence of verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193355/omission-of-for-with-various-quantified-time-intervals-influence-of-verb) thread. Your question is comparable to that about the omission of 'for' with time intervals. 'The FTSE has gone up 2%' and 'The FTSE has gone up by 2%' are both idiomatic, and the deletion of the preposition causes no problems with ambiguity. But 'up [by] 500%' can both be problematic.

Comment: Thank you Edwin. Your comment is useful and helpful for me.:)