# How long have you been married (for)?

Tags: verbs, tenses

Is there a difference between the following sentences?

1. How long have you been married?
2. How long have you been married for?

Comment: Not really, the second one is a reordering of the sentence "For how long have you been married?" and, I think, the first one is a shortened form of the second one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Omission of 'for' with various quantified time intervals: influence of verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193355/omission-of-for-with-various-quantified-time-intervals-influence-of-verb) 'How long have you been there [for]?' 'We've lived here [for] twelve years' are very similar.